# How to allow iOS 7 iPhone to sync? "Trust this computer" appears endlessly

Tags: ios

My iPhone 4S won't connect to my computer when running Ubuntu 13.04. The "Trust this computer" prompt just endlessly pops up. Without actually connecting.

Any ideas? Maybe this is just going to be it with iOS 7.

Comment: Where do you try to connect the device to? In Ubuntu? If yes which version do you use? Also keep in mind iOS 7 is not released yet. Maybe you should post this question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [It seems bug isn't fixed yet][1]


  [1]: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1207812

Answer (score 6):

This functionality was built in to iOS 7 in order to stop a security issue in iOS, where Linux systems present themselves as a charger, leaving the connected iPhone/iPad vulnerable to manipulation through Linux. Hence it would be logical for such a function to work properly in Ubuntu.

Haven't been able to find any solution to it yet, but the problem seems to be the question becomes an endless loop.

Information on the new functionality in iOS 7 to ask if you trust the computer connecting may be found here: http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/apple-fixes-threat-from-fake-iphone-chargers-in-ios-7

Comment: Thanks for the background info. Is there any solution yet? I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS right now. Will 14.04 have the same issue -- or is it likely to have it?

Answer (score 0):

**All credit goes to bleeves**
Original answer can be found @ [iOS 7 Locked Bug via Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371711/ios-7-locked-bug-via-ubuntu-13-10)

This issue is an attempt by Apple to stop the use of fake charging cables. You can solve the trust-loop error with IOS7 mobile devices by installing the latest release of libimobiledevice.

For 12.04:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ingo/ios7support
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you get “lock down error”, try using the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown
```

For 13.10 you can download the .deb package from the launchpad site [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1207812/+attachment/3941542/+files/libimobiledevice4_1.1.6-git20140105_amd64.deb).

For Ipad users that are seeing the 'Not Charging' message on their device when plugged in via usb:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ipad-charge
```

Reboot, and enjoy.