# Can I connect my iPhone now that I have updated to iOS 7?

Tags: wine, apple, iphone, playonlinux

Basically, I get an endlessly looping pop-up asking "do I want to trust this computer?" When I click 'trust' it just won't connect.

Will this problem ever be solved or should I just restore to a previous version of iOS, or perhaps there is a way of using iTunes through PlayOnLinux or some other solution?

Comment: iTunes + PlayOnLinux + Wine won't help, the issue of iTunes not being able to detect the USB device will still be an issue, that's a known issue too.  I don't think there's a solution for this yet.

Comment: For the answer to your problem see my response in this thread:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/336112/how-to-allow-ios-7-iphone-to-sync-trust-this-computer-appears-endlessly