# Access files on iPhone 4s from Ubuntu?

Tags: files, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s with ios7. When i plug in my iPhone on Ubuntu 13.10, the window says my phone is locked and I cant access the files. I push "trust" Computer on my phone and it just keeps popping up over and over again, but it never unlocks on Ubuntu so I can't access my files that are on my phone. Please help!

Comment: I have added a solution to the 'trust this computer' loop [on this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336112/how-to-allow-ios-7-iphone-to-sync-trust-this-computer-appears-endlessly). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't access the files i iphone4s , me too Using the Same Phone, Last week i was Sync 1500 Songs to my iphone 4s Using Rythmbox Musci player, the sync was Done, And Space were occupied in iphone too, But while looking into my phones music player there was nothing, Used itunes in Windows and works.. Ubuntu Wont Support for iphone ..

Answer (score 0):

It will only work if you use [software](https://softorino.com/how-to-transfer-music-from-computer-to-iphone/), it will not work through the cable. Try [WALTR2](https://softorino.com/waltr/) should be suitable for iPhone 4s.