# Ubuntu 13.04/13.10 won't trust iPhone

Tags: iphone

Users have reported issues with connecting their iPhones 5 to Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10. The iPhone reports "Trust the currently connected computer?" When the users selects 'Trust', it continues to ask.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1207812

Comment: This is no longer an issue, I have posted the solution on [this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/336112/how-to-allow-ios-7-iphone-to-sync-trust-this-computer-appears-endlessly

Answer (score 4):

I recently checked out the bug tracking page and I noticed a solution. The solution is to download libimobiledevice4_1.1.6-git20140105_amd64.deb. This can be found here:

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/161787269/libimobiledevice4_1.1.6-git20140105_amd64.deb

Once downloaded, point your terminal to the location of the .deb file and execute the following:

```
> sudo dpkg -i libimobiledevice4_1.1.6-git20140105_amd64.deb
```

According to the bug page, other users have reported having success with this update library as well.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1207812

I downloaded this and was successful with connecting my iPhone 5.

**Update**

Just want to clarify that this lib is currently for 64-bit versions of Ubuntu 13.04/13.10.

Comment: @bmike. Migrating sounds good! If I find any similar question on this site, I'll post a comment pointing to the migrated link.

Answer (score 0):

> **Works for me.**
>
> Here is my post:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1215098/comments/67/